# CANopen SYNC Message Detection with STM32L476

Tags: c, stm32, can-bus, canopen

With an STM32L476 as CANopen node I have to detect (consume) the CANopen SYNC message on the CAN bus as fast as possible, probably in the ISR context. All other CANopen messages (beside the CANopen SYNC message) must be processed as well. However, I need a seperate interrupt for the CANopen SYNC message reception.
Anyone an idea how to do that?

Comment: You can configure the can peripheral to use two interrupt handlers, one for the reception of the sync message and another for the reception of all other can-open messages.

Comment: Don't know about this specific MCU, but many of them have multiple inboxes with separate filters, where you can setup individual ISR for each inbox. Look up if this one has that capability.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny Many STM32 have archaic, ~20 year old CAN controllers so they don't support mailboxes. I think there are newer STM32 with modern CAN controllers however, "STM32" could mean anything.

Comment: Ok so I looked it up, this one uses the ancient "bxCAN". Ideally you should pick a modern microcontroller instead. Funny how ST keeps releasing MCUs with this old junk inside. Motorola had better CAN controllers in their MCUs than this in the late 1990s...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to get you going:

```
CAN_ITConfig(CANx, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING | CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_FULL, ENABLE);

void CAN_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING_IRQHandler(void) {
  received_sync_message = true;
  CAN_ClearITPendingBit(CANx, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING);
}

void CAN_RX_FIFO0_FULL_IRQHandler(void) {    
  CAN_ClearITPendingBit(CANx, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_FULL);
}
```